# Failing to update rows in the database, only able to update one row with corresponding ID to UserId

Tags: php

I am trying to update rows in a table of items. The database has ID for item id and UserId for the id of the user who created the item.
The problem is the the update is only updating the first row which has item ID 1 and UserId 1 thats all.
Here is the update query.

```
<?php
    require_once 'conn.php';

    if(ISSET($_POST['update'])){
        $userid     = $_SESSION['gtsuid'];
        $ItemName   = $_POST['ItemName'];
        $ItemType   = $_POST['ItemType'];
        $Quantity   = $_POST['Quantity'];
        $Price      = $_POST['Price'];
        $Amount     = $_POST['Amount'];
        $BDate      = $_POST['BDate'];

        $query = "UPDATE `items` SET `ItemName` = :ItemName, `ItemType` = :ItemType, `Quantity` = :Quantity, `Price` = :Price, `Amount` = :Amount, `BDate` = :BDate WHERE `ID` = :userid";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ItemName', $ItemName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ItemType', $ItemType);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Quantity', $Quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Price', $Price);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Amount', $Amount);
        $stmt->bindParam(':BDate', $BDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);

        $stmt->execute();
        $conn = null;

        header('location: index.php');

    }
?>
```

And the database:

[image: database]

I really don't know where I am going wrong as I am still new to this.

Comment: You never bind a variable to :userId

Comment: From description shouldn't ``WHERE `ID` = :userid`` be ``WHERE `userID` = :userid``? ... and you need to bind it.

Comment: Negative votes, is it a way of discouraging people from asking?

Comment: user3783243 I have tried WHERE `userID` = :userid, WHERE ID = :ID but to no avail.

Comment: Negative votes are pretty useless. They are meant to indicate the question doesn't have enough information but people use them for all sorts of things. You will need to clairfy what fails and when. Give exact examples of what is being passed in. You also should show what error reporting or some debugging shows. e.g. does https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php show rows were updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue sorted out. Here is the solution in case of future reference.
SOLUTION:
1. Declare ID like this: $ID   = $_POST['ID']; as shown below;

```
if(ISSET($_POST['update'])){
    $userid     = $_SESSION['gtsuid'];
    $ID         = $_POST['ID'];
    $ItemName   = $_POST['ItemName'];
    $ItemType   = $_POST['ItemType'];
    $Quantity   = $_POST['Quantity'];
    $Price      = $_POST['Price'];
    $Amount     = $_POST['Amount'];
    $BDate      = $_POST['BDate'];
```

Then also bind the ID.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ItemName', $ItemName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ItemType', $ItemType);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Quantity', $Quantity);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Price', $Price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Amount', $Amount);
    $stmt->bindParam(':BDate', $BDate);
```

2. Echo the ID on submit button like this:

In my case I was missing the statements below:

```
  $ID = $_POST['ID'];
  $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
  <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
```

Hitherto, thank you all for your contributions.